# php dynamic variable with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the variable $id in a loop which is the div id, so the div id is always changing.  I know with javascript it's done like this.

```
<div id='$id' onclick='myfunction($id)' >
```

How do i use jquery to get variables i don't know their id?

Comment: This depends greatly on your code and what you are trying to do, you can generate jQuery from php and insert the variables, you can use classes, you can use data attributes etc. but it all depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF youre using jquery there is no real reason (other than some edge cases) to use the event handler attributes on the element like `onclick`. You should do everything unobtrusively. For example:

HTML:
`<div id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="some_class">`

JS:

```
$.ready(function(){
  $('.some_class').click(function(){
     myFunction($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

Or lets say you ids conform to a certain format like `my_function_10`, then you can use [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

`<div id="my_function_<?php echo $id; ?>">`

Then you can do:

```
$.ready(function(){
  $('[id^="my_function_"]').click(function(){
     myFunction($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Please explain this bit - '[id^="my_function_"]'

Comment: So that will let you search for ids beginning with `my_function_` so in reference to your other question you could then use `substr` like: `var id = $('[id^="my_function_"]').attr('id').substr(13);`

Answer (score 2):

Use a class.

```
<div id='$id' class="myDiv" onclick='myfunction($id)' >
```

Then you can do this in jQuery:

```
$(".myDiv").each(function() {
    // write code here.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should assign a class to those divs, and use jQuery to loop through all of the elements with that class:

```
$( ".your_div_class" ).each( function() { ... });
```

Also, you will need to output the PHP variables appropriately:

```
<div id="<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick="myfunction('<?php echo $id; ?>')" >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use inline event handlers you can always use `onclick="myfunction(this.id);"` to pass the ID. Or even better, `onclick="myfunction.call(this);"` so `this` points to the element inside the function.

But since you have jQuery available, there's no good reason to write `onsomething` a single time!